# android simplecursoradapter errors out every time

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

I'm stuck trying to create a simple cursor adapter. I've checked every website I can find, and all the threads here and I just can't see what's wrong.

```
gcDBAssist dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Cursor cursor;
String display;
String TAG = "Listing the database";
ListView listTimeline;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

static final String[] FROM = { gcDBAssist.C_ID, gcDBAssist.C_TIME, gcDBAssist.C_SCORE, gcDBAssist.C_LEVEL, gcDBAssist.C_POSTED, gcDBAssist.C_USER };
static final int[] TO = { R.id.textID, R.id.textTime, R.id.textScore, R.id.textLevel, R.id.textPosted, R.id.textUser };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.time_list);
  listTimeline = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTimeline);

  dbHelper = new gcDBAssist(this);
  db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

  super.onResume();

  //get the data
  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " +gcDBAssist.TABLE, null);       
  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, FROM, TO, 0);
  listTimeline.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I've run some checks and I can access the database using a `while(cursor.moveToNext())`.

Comment: Where is the error?Please be more specific

Comment: Is there an exception or a sqlite error?

Comment: When it gets to the adapter = new simplecursoradapter section I get a FATAL EXCEPTION: main Android Runtime error. If I comment that line, and the setAdapter line out I can access the data returned in the cursor.

Comment: After another couple of hours of trawling through the code and the internet I've found the problem. I had labelled my id as 'id' in the table not as '_id'. Which explains why it doesn't throw an error when I iterate through, but does throw an error when I try to set an adapter. Thanks for the help.